# Navigate through views in storyboard xcode

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, navigation, xcode6

I'm using segue show to navigate from a view to another. I'm using

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Nextview", sender: self)
```

to navigate around, but i don't quite understand this functionality. Does this make a new instance of view - if yes, does the old view get dialoged/deleted? Another thing is should i use the same method when i want to navigate back?

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("PreviousView", sender: self)
```

- if not, what should i do to navigate back? Hope you guys can help

Comment: If you have a navigation controller at the beginning, the segue back will be handled for you with the back button.

Comment: You can think of it like this, the navigation controller is a view stack. When you click to perform the segue to the next view, it will create and add the view onto the navigation stack. When you press the navigation back button, the view gets popped off the stack and deallocated and it segues back to the previous view on the stack.

Comment: @Rasputin And what should i use to navigate from view to view in that view stack? is performSegueWithIdentifier the right way?